# Redirect to a custom page on 503 error in Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balance, ingress

When our site is getting deployed, the Ingress gets created and before I could get any response I get 503 for 5-6 minutes (time taken to startup).

We need to configure our ingress to redirect to a static page that is custom-made instead of the 503 error. Can I add an annotation to achieve this? If yes, please give me an example for redirect config using the status code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in configuration/annotation to handle this.

Although, you can use the [server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) annotation to create a custom configuration that [intercepts](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) the error 503, proxying the request to a service that is serving your custom error page. Example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 503 = @errorpages;
      
      location @errorpages {
        proxy_set_header X-Code $status;
        proxy_pass http://errors-svc.default.svc.cluster.local;
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ameba.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: I was stuck in how to pass the service to proxy_pass, thanks ;)